# Google App Scripts - Create Google form using CreateForm() function and run MarkForm() function on form submit

Tags: google-apps-script

*Aim*

I am currently using Google App Scripts to create a form that one submitted sends an email to the respondent with a detailed summary of their results.

*Methods so Far*

To achieve this, I have written two functions: one function to create the form and a second function to mark and email the summary of the results to the respondent.

```
function CreateForm(){
//Working code to create form here
}

function MarkForm(){
//Working code to create and email detailed summary of results
}
```

In order to make this code work correctly, I have to:

1. Create the form using the CreateForm() function
2. Open the new form and paste the MarkForm() function into the script editor.
3. Set a trigger OnFormSubmit to run the function MarkForm()

*Question*

Is it possible to do the three steps above using **one** function?

Comment: Is each form unique? Are they on different sheets? What are you marking? From what you've described, no, this would not be possible in one function because you would have to somehow indefinitely stall a function while you wait for a response. Two functions is much cleaner as far as maintenance, too.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Brian. Sorry for the lack of details in the original question. The CreateForm() function creates a new form with 10 mathematics questions. The MarkForm() function compares the users response to the correct response and needs to run when the form is submitted. I am looking for a way to install a trigger for the MarkForm() function to run when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "On Form Submit" installable trigger to run a function when a form response comes in. Reading [the Google Triggers guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) in the Apps Script Documentation will help.

Do the following:

1. Choose Edit > Current project's triggers. You see a panel with the message No triggers set up. Click here to add one now.
2. Click the link.
3. Under Run, select the function you want executed by the trigger. (`MarkForm()`)
4. Under Events, select From Spreadsheet.
5. From the next drop-down list, select On form submit.
6. Click Save.

Now, when a submission comes in, the form response will be marked automatically. This trigger is an installable trigger, which means it needs to be set up through the menu rather than calling a function like `onEdit()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Brian. Still not quite what I am looking for though. I am aware that I am able to install a trigger manually using the UI of google app scripts in the way that you have suggested, however I am trying to install the trigger for MarkFunctions() programatically.

Comment: If you want it on a form submit, then no, you cannot.